# I wish to make a donation and get an invoice

Tags: donation

Ubuntu is great and deserves some gratitude, but if it can be deducted from my taxes it's even greater! How may I get an invoice for the donation I am about to make?
Thanks,
Mikhail

Answer (score 1):

Neither Ubuntu or Canonical are registered charities. And I'm not sure you can say an optional donation is a necessary business expense.

I'm not an accountant though...

Use their [contact page](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact) to talk to somebody at Canonical.